# RABBITMQ_02 - Failed to acknowledge offset ERROR

Tags: streaming

I have a pipeline that read from RabbitMQ and loads it to kinesis stream and i'm getting the following error:

any idea what could be the reason?

Thanks

```
UNKNOWN java.lang.RuntimeException: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: RABBITMQ_02 - Failed to acknowledge offset '2945': java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.production.ProductionSourceOffsetCommitterOffsetTracker.commitOffset(ProductionSourceOffsetCommitterOffsetTracker.java:80)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.executeRunner(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:857)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.runSourceLessBatch(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:823)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.runPollSource(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:563)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunner.run(ProductionPipelineRunner.java:383)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:512)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipeline.run(ProductionPipeline.java:112)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.ProductionPipelineRunnable.run(ProductionPipelineRunnable.java:74)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.standalone.StandaloneRunner.start(StandaloneRunner.java:756)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.runner.common.AsyncRunner.lambda$start$3(AsyncRunner.java:152)
  at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:227)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
  at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:223)
  at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:227)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
  at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:223)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.metrics.MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService$MetricsTask.run(MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService.java:100)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: RABBITMQ_02 - Failed to acknowledge offset '2945': java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.rabbitmq.RabbitSource.commit(RabbitSource.java:187)
  at com.streamsets.pipeline.configurablestage.DSourceOffsetCommitter.commit(DSourceOffsetCommitter.java:41)
  at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.production.ProductionSourceOffsetCommitterOffsetTracker.commitOffset(ProductionSourceOffsetCommitterOffsetTracker.java:75) ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because RabbitMQ has timed out while the batch was being processed. Check the RabbitMQ error log.

If this is the case, try reducing the batch size in the RabbitMQ origin.

Comment: Nothing in error log and already tried to reduce batch size to 5 and even 1 but still got this error..

Comment: Not sure what it could be then... One troubleshooting tactic is to replace the destination with 'Trash' and see if it works. You could also ask in one of the StreamSets community channels - you'll reach more expertise there: https://streamsets.com/community

Comment: thanks, asked already in streamsets community, but still havnt get any answer